# gnuplot - How to extract pm3d interpolated data?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to smooth some sparse data I have (format x,y,z) in a gnuplot graph. I need to plot using `plot` and the `with image` option because files generated with `pm3d map` are exceedingly oversized. What I like about `pm3d map` is that I can smooth my data with `interpolate` in such a way that the interpolated point only considers neighboring points (`dgrid3d` considers every point in the graph for the smoothing).

Hence what I want to do is `set table` and then export the `pm3d map` data with the interpolation set to whatever I desire, then use that data to do a `plot ... with image`. The problem is that when I do the following:

```
set table "out.dat"
set pm3d map interpolate 10,10
splot "in.dat"
```

gnuplot ignores the `interpolate` option and simply writes to "out.dat" the same info that was written in "in.dat".

Any ideas?

Alternatively, any stand alone code that interpolates 3D data in the same fashion of pm3d would also be useful.

**Edit:**

Apparently, I am using at work an "oldish" version of gnuplot: gnuplot 4.2 patchlevel 6, which only accepts the `dgrid3d` behavior as described above. At home, I am using a newer version (gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 3) which comes with the option `set dgrid3d {<rows>{,<cols>}} splines`. This does more or less what I want.

Comment: Right, and gnuplot tells you that: `Tabular output of this 3D plot style not implemented`. Are you sure, that `set dgrid3d` is nothing for you? It doesn't use every point, but also only the neighboring points, which are weighted depending on their distance to the new grid points. I have no data for testing, but from the description it looks good to me. You might need to play around with the various smoothing options.

Comment: Unfortunately `dgrid3d` uses all the data points. If you type `help set dgrid3d` you will get `In some cases, small norm values produce a grid point reflecting the average of distant data points rather than a local average, while large values of norm may produce "steps" with several grid points having the same value as the closest data point, rather than making a smooth transition between adjacent data points.`, which is exactly my problem.