# Gnuplot: how to avoid white margin in PDF through adjusting page size and other parameters

Tags: pdf, gnuplot, margin

Here is my code:

```
set term pdfcairo enhanced dashed size 5,3;
set output "plot.pdf";
f(x,y)=sin(1.3*x)*cos(.9*y)+cos(.8*x)*sin(1.9*y)+cos(y*.2*x)
set size square
set xrange [-5:5]
set yrange [-5:5]
set contour base
set cntrparam level incremental -3, 0.5, 3
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
set pm3d map
set isosample 250, 250
unset key
set lmargin at screen 0.1;
set rmargin at screen 0.95;
set bmargin at screen 0.2;
set tmargin at screen 0.95;
splot f(x,y) with pm3d
```

Here is the corresponding plot:

[image]

There are white margins around the plot. How can I eliminate these white margins through editing the gnuplot code?

Comment: `pm3d` and `set margins` don't like each other. I would suggest two options: 1) You use `plot ... with image` for which you can't use functions, so would need to export you data using a `table`. This would allow you to set the margins with no problems. 2) You use an external utility to clip the PDF. I normally use `pdfcrop`.

Comment: A third (ugly) option: 3) Modify the `size` attribute of the plot to something larger than `set size 1,1`, e.g. `set size 1.5,1.25` until you fit the image to what you like; this is not very systematic and would need a lot of trial and error. Of all three options, I use 1) myself.

Comment: I tried to set the page size in the terminal. But I found it can not completely remove the margins. If I can set the position of the figure in a page, I can then remove the margin completely. I just do not know whether there is such function in Gnuplot: set figure position in a page.

Comment: @Miguel Plotting with image can be done with functions: `plot '++' using 1:2:(f($1,$2))`, but unfortunately `plot` doesn't support contours, at it usually does 2d plots.

Comment: @Christoph I didn't know the dummy file accepted two variables, very useful!

Comment: Is there a way to have interpolate for with image like "set pm3d interpolate 0,0". I am actually plotting from a data file.

Comment: @Leo It's not the terminal size, but the figure size that I suggested to change, then you can offset the position of the plot using `set origin`, which by default is `set origin 0,0`. To keep your figure centered, if you do `set size 1.5,1.25` then you should offset it by `set origin -0.25,-0.125`.

Comment: @Leo Have a look at this old question of mine and Christoph's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771210/gnuplot-how-to-extract-pm3d-interpolated-data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks Miguel.

I now set page size and margins. After several tests:

```
set term pdfcairo enhanced dashed size 3.2,3;
set output "plot.pdf";
f(x,y)=sin(1.3*x)*cos(.9*y)+cos(.8*x)*sin(1.9*y)+cos(y*.2*x)
set size square
set xrange [-5:5]
set yrange [-5:5]
set contour base
set cntrparam level incremental -3, 0.5, 3
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
set pm3d map
set isosample 250, 250
unset key
set lmargin at screen 0.05;
set rmargin at screen 0.9;
set bmargin at screen 0.1;
set tmargin at screen 0.95;
splot f(x,y) with pm3d
```

Here is the figure:

[image]