# Empty space in ratio constrained gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to make a density plot with constraint axis in gnuplot, but I have a lot of empty space outside my plot

```
reset
set term postscript enhanced eps color
set output "verif_thetaK_60deg.eps"
set pm3d map
set size ratio -1
set xtics 0.5
set autoscale xfixmax

rayon=0.35

set object 1 circle at 0,5./2 size rayon front fs empty border lw 3.0
set object 2 circle at sqrt(3),5./2 size rayon front fs empty border lw 3.0
set object 3 circle at sqrt(3),0.5 size rayon front fs empty border lw 3.0
set object 4 circle at 0.5*sqrt(3),1 size rayon front fs empty border lw 3.0
set object 5 circle at 0.5*sqrt(3),2 size rayon front fs empty border lw 3.0
set object 6 circle at 0,0.5 size rayon front fs empty border lw 3.0

splot "verif_thetaK_60deg.dat" u 1:2:3 notitle
```

I have tried using `multiplot` with `set origin`, it is working for the empty space but now the circles are rotated. I do not understand.
Someone to help me?
Here are the first lines of my sample data

```
0.  0.  1.4897029029511362
0.  0.02857142857142857 1.5198145790443847
0.  0.05714285714285714 1.6051617239962799
0.  0.08571428571428572 1.7477181570182962
0.  0.11428571428571428 1.9508130394308165
0.  0.14285714285714285 2.219107847798675
0.  0.17142857142857143 2.5584267524091646
0.  0.2 2.9078002844476583
0.  0.22857142857142856 3.261016162180486
0.  0.2571428571428571  3.61098658139621
0.  0.2857142857142857  3.9502081600876053
0.  0.3142857142857143  4.271128101449691
```

I have let a blank line each time the first column change.

At the moment my image looks like this:

[image: plot with large margins]

Comment: Perhaps you could include some images to show the problem you are having? Also, a sample of your data would be useful.

Comment: I cannot add images, I have not enough reputation (10 is required)

Comment: As I recall, you can still upload the images, so if you upload them and leave the links in your question then someone else will be able to insert them for you.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, however, I put the image as my user picture, maybe you are able to download it and publish it?

Comment: Unfortunately that image is too small to be useful. If you click on the "Image" button and try to add your image, it should produce some markup in your question like `![image description here][1]` and there will be a link at the bottom of your question. If you remove the exclamation mark, you will be left with a plain link to your picture. Then someone else can insert it for you.

Comment: @lambertmular is it necessary for you to have `set size ratio -1`? If yes then I believe with `set size ratio -1` Gnuplot will try to set the size such that the unit length on x and y axis is the same.

Comment: Yes it is absolutely necessary to have `set size ratio -1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the margins and the size correct requires some fiddling:

First you must set a canvas size which better fits the shape of your plot e.g. `set terminal postscript eps size 2in,4in`.

Then you must adjust the `lmargin` and/or the `bmargin` manually. That requires some iterations to get it right.

As good notice: The upcoming version 5.0 has an option `set view map scale ...` which greatly simplifies this.

Alternatively you can also use a tool like `epstool` to correct the bounding box:

```
epstool --bbox --copy --output cropped.eps original.eps
```

For a similar question, see [Gnuplot: how to avoid white margin in PDF through adjusting page size and other parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23505711/2604213).

Comment: Thank you! by adding a `set margin`, I was able to do what I want. However, it is not working so nicely. I hope the next version will improve this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `set size ratio -1` Gnuplot will try to set the plot size such that the unit length on x and y axis is same.

You can get your desired result by stating the canvas size, following are one set of dimension, you can play around with them to suite your requirement.

```
set term postscript size 1.25, 2.25
```

I get the following plot with the amount of data that you've posted:

[image] [image]

Comment: This solution does not allow to control the marge, I still have the same amount of white space. I think my problem comes from the constrained ratio. Any other idea to control the white space?

Comment: @lambertmular As I said earlier, with `set size ratio -1` the margins will be auto determined. I have added the plot that I get, to me it seems that the margins have been "marginalized" :) I'm using Gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 3 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @lambertmular If you can try other terminals like png then you may can use `lmargin, rmargin, tmargin, bmargin` all set to zero with explicit canvas size. Although I'm not too sure how `pm3d` will look on that. I have also added a PNG plot with canvas size to my answer above.